# Type annotations for dynamically created subclasses

Tags: python, dynamic, types, typing

I want to dynamically create child classes at startup with the `type()` function. Everything works as expected.
I know this isn't great, but I am bound to a framework and have to do it this way. The other option is to generate source code...

Functional equivalent to my code:

```py
class BaseEntity:
    id: str


def make_new_entity(name: str, attrs: dict) -> type:
    return type('RuntimeEntity', (BaseEntity,), attrs)


RuntimeEntity: ??? = make_new_entity('RuntimeEntity', {'id': 'entity.RuntimeEntity'})
```

Is there a way to provide a bound to the returned type? Basically the equivalent of

```py
E = TypeVar('E', bound='BaseEntity')
```

I have also looked at the `types` module.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typing.Type` lets you specify that the value should be an actual type, rather than an instance of that type.

```
from typing import Type

class BaseEntity:
    id: str


def make_new_entity(name: str, attrs: dict) -> Type[BaseEntity]:
    return type('RuntimeEntity', (BaseEntity,), attrs)


RuntimeEntity: Type[BaseEntity] = make_new_entity('RuntimeEntity', {'id':     'entity.RuntimeEntity'})
```

A value of type `Type[BaseEntity]` can be `BaseEntity` itself, or any class that inherits from `BaseEntity`. (The term to describe this is *covariance*. If `Type` were *invariant*, `Type[BaseEntity]` would accept `BaseEntity` itself only.)

Comment: That's great, thank you! I tried that, but got confused as PyCharm says "Expected type 'Type[BaseEntity]', got 'type' instead". IntelliSense works on the instance though. Probably a bug or impossible to lint.

Comment: It's even worse in the dict I'm putting it in: "Expected type `Dict[str, Type[BaseEntity]]`, got `Dict[str, type]`" instead

Comment: I don't get any error with `mypy` on the code shown.